# How to Fetch the Shortcode Parameters Value in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

```
[amazon_s3 bucket=my_bucket_name object=my_file_name.ext]
```

Hi all i need to know how to fetch the parameter value in the above shortcode. For Example: Object is the attributes then how can i fetch the object value `my_file_name.ext`. I am using the woocommerce s3 plugin. I am not sure i customized the woocommerce to fetch the file name show in my account page here is the code.

```
 function filename_wc_downloads( $link, $download )
    {
           $order = new WC_Order( $download['order_id'] );
        $download_file_urls = $order->get_downloadable_file_urls( 
            $download['product_id'], 
            null, 
            $download['download_id'] 
        );

        foreach( $download_file_urls as $key => $value )
        {
            if( $value == $download['download_url'] )
            {
                $url_parts = explode( '/', parse_url( $key, PHP_URL_PATH ) );
                $file_name = end( $url_parts );
                $link = '<a href="' 
                    . esc_url( $download['download_url'] ) 
                    . '">' 
                    . $download['download_name'] 
                    . '</a> <small>( ' 
                    . $file_name 
                    . ' )</small>';
            }               
        }
        return $link;
    }
```

In a Woocommerce all products are uploaded into the media library of upload folder. The above code is to fetch the filename show in my account page if they using direct file path. If i pasted the above shortcode in the product url, that above code doesn't help to fetch the filename. so i need to know from the shortcode how can i get the object value based on this to show the file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

amazon_s3 is your shortcode containing $atts bucket and object

when you use wordpress function add_shortcode('amazon_s3', 'your_function_name');

it automatically converts your attributes defined in [amazan_s3 .... to $atts

e.g.

```
function your_funnction_name($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'bucket' => '',
        'object' => ''
    ), $atts));

   return $object;
}
```